# Referring to private singleton property within singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton

In the case of the singleton class seen below, what is the proper way to initialize MyList? Do I refer directly to the field MyList (Option 1) or to Instance.MyList (Option 2)? What's best practice here? My gut says go through Instance, but I'm second-guessing myself and cannot find a definitive answer anywhere.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly static Lazy<Foo> _instance =
        new Lazy<Foo>(() => new Foo());

    private List<string> MyList;

    public static Foo Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    private Foo()
    {
        MyList = new List<string> {"a","b","c"}; //Option 1

        Instance.MyList = new List<string> {"a","b","c"};  //Option 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between the 2 options. Personally I like to use `this.PropertyName`, even though VS keeps bugging me to remove the `this.`.

Comment: Let me update to a better example...

Comment: I wouldn't call Instance from the constructor. Again, I don't think there should be any difference, but It just seems strange.

Comment: Option 1 looks cleaner for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, I would say that either way is fine. That being said, I prefer the option that doesn't use the "Instance" identifier. The concept of the instance really belongs to the code outside of the singleton class. Inside the class, the fact that it is a singleton should be well known. Thus, specifying the Instance identifier is redundant.

Comment: Logical and concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton pattern is for creating types that can only have one instance, but are still treated like instances of a type, rather than being treated as just a type like static types.  So if `MyList` is part of the single instance, then it should be an instance variable on that instance, not a static member of the class.

One of the perks of the Singleton pattern is that it is easier mock for testing and also easier to transition to using multiple instances later, compared to using static members and classes.  For these purposes, making `MyList` an instance member also helps.

If using an instance, you can write `MyList` or `this.MyList` within that instance or `Instance.MyList` from other places.  None of these are more correct than any others, it really depends on what you find readable.  The important thing is to not mix conventions, which is the worst readability option.

Comment: While that might be true, it does not answer the question at all.